# FTP Client listFiles() work in some machines

Tags: java, apache, ftp, ftp-client

I have a program that make use of FTP Client, it is running in several machines and it stoped working in one of those machines.

Making the debug I can see that the problem is on `listFiles(), listNames()...` But it work's perfect giving me the name of the directory when I make `printWorkingDirectory()` or when I make `FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftp.getReplyCode())` it brings me the true value.

I have also made `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()`, `ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE)`.

I'm lost, can you please help me?

Comment: What FTP client (package, website, vendor)? Also, define "it stopped working".

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the data connection is blocked - most likely in a router or firewall.  You need to  have the machine "behind" a NAT device be the active one.

What is the exact network configuration between the two machines you have problems with?